Almost all of my laravel 8 add data form give me 302 when submitted
this is happening after i added Quill text editor, perhaps. Suddenly, all my add form return 302 and doesnt successfully add data to database. i use laravel 8 on windows 10 with xampp.
this is example form view
<form method="POST"
                                    action="{{ route('produk2_store') }}"
                                    >
                                    @csrf

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="nama"
                                            class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nama Produk') }}</label>

                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input id="nama" type="text"
                                                class="form-control @error('nama') is-invalid @enderror"
                                                name="nama" value="{{ old('nama') }}" required
                                                autocomplete="nama" autofocus>

                                            @error('nama')
                                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                </span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="perusahaan_id"
                                            class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Perusahaan') }}</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <select name="perusahaan_id" id="perusahaan_id" class="form-select">
                                                @foreach($perusahaans as $perusahaan)
                                                    <option value="{{ $perusahaan->perusahaan_id }}">{{ $perusahaan->nama }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                        <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-3">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                {{ __('Simpan') }}
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>

this is the controller
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Produk2;
use App\Models\Perusahaan;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Produk2Controller extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $produk2 = new Produk2;
        $produk2->nama = $request->input('nama');
        $produk2->perusahaan_id = $request->input('perusahaan_id');
        $produk2->save();

        return redirect()->route('produk2_index')->with('success', 'Berhasil tambah produk.');
    }


i tried removing the @csrf but still doesnt work.
i tried removing enctype:multipart/form-data but still doesnt work.
i also try artisan config:clear and optimize:clear it still doesnt work.
i also try remove quill text editor, still doesnt work.
i also try
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'nama' => 'required',
        ]);
        $produk2 = new Produk2;
        $produk2->nama = $validatedData['nama'];
        $produk2->perusahaan_id = $request->input('perusahaan_id');
        $produk2->save();
        dd($produk2);
        return;
    }

in my controller but still it doesnt go to method but refresh the add form only.
i also try in firefox, no luck.
i also try remove spatie/laravel-permission, no luck.

It indicates that the page has been moved. I think you need to find out where it was moved. See more here: https://www.semrush.com/blog/302-redirect/?kw=&cmp=EE_SRCH_DSA_Blog_EN&label=dsa_pagefeed&Network=g&Device=c&utm_content=676606915187&kwid=dsa-2185834088336&cmpid=18361923498&agpid=157305244791&BU=Core&extid=105138959716&adpos=&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwyJqzBhBaEiwAWDRJVAUhTGb9E-jUSZjueaGKiBR13DLFxwIExp_vf-KQnYEOJ21F2sLvJxoCDE4QAvD_BwE
